# sbt looks at .ivy2/local but jars are in .ivy2/cache

Tags: sbt

Are the locations intentional? I have an issue where sbt always seems to fetch dependency externally rather than from local. When external resolvers are removed, the dependency cannot be resolved because the path .ivy2/local does not exist.

Comment: Trying to solve the same problem -- adding "cache" to ~\.sbt\resolvers doesn't seem to work, as cache isn't one of its known keywords. Is it a matter of configuring the resolvers setting in the project build?